# Quickly move email to folder after read in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

## Background

In Gmail, you can use rules to automatically label an email. The automatically labeled email will remain in the inbox. Then, when you archive the email (by pressing the "e" keyboard button) the email moves from inbox and to its label.
In Outlook, if you use rules to automatically label an email, it moves to its folder on arrival. Therefore, you're unable to see all the new emails in your inbox.

## Question

How can I make Outlook quickly/automatically send an email to its folder only after I've read it?

Answer (score 2):

There are many Advanced Rule Wizard actions in Outlook. You could Send to Folder, but wait until Flagged for Action. Read it and Flag it and then after you have read it, it will move. Many such rules for you to review.

Comment: Where do I find the "Advanced Rule Wizard"?
The regular rules are not triggered when the email flag changes.

Comment: "Inbox rules run as soon as email arrives in your mailbox"
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/organize-your-inbox-with-archive-sweep-and-other-tools-in-outlook-com-19eee6b9-09a1-4db6-b5d6-37644190884f